# libgdx 3d rendering, I'm getting low fps

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, rendering

I'm not sure if I do 3d rendering correctly? Below is a method with my 3d rendering method. When I run my game on desktop it works fine with 60fps, but when I run it on android it works just with 15fps. When I comment out this method I get 60fps too, so I think that problem is in my 3d rendering code.

Can you tell me if it's correct or not?

```
private void draw3d() {
        gameViewport.apply();

        modelBatch.begin(gameCamera);
        modelBatch.render(highwayInstance, environment);
        modelBatch.render(highway2Instance, environment);
        modelBatch.render(highwayLines, environment);
        modelBatch.render(buttons, environment);
        if (activeMetronomeFirsts.size != 0) {
            int activeMetronomeFirstLength = activeMetronomeFirsts.size;
            for (int i = activeMetronomeFirstLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeMetronomeFirsts.get(i).getMetronomeInstance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeMetronomes.size != 0) {
            int activeMetronomeLength = activeMetronomes.size;
            for (int i = activeMetronomeLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeMetronomes.get(i).getMetronomeInstance(),environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeSnares.size != 0) {
            int activeSnareLength = activeSnares.size;
            for (int i = activeSnareLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeSnares.get(i).getSnareInstance(),environment);
                //activeSnares.get(i).draw(modelBatch);
            }
        }
        if (activeHiHats.size != 0) {
            int activeHiHatLength = activeHiHats.size;
            for (int i = activeHiHatLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeHiHats.get(i).getHiHatInstance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeTom1s.size != 0) {
            int activeTom1Length = activeTom1s.size;
            for (int i = activeTom1Length; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeTom1s.get(i).getTom1Instance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeRides.size != 0) {
            int activeRideLength = activeRides.size;
            for (int i = activeRideLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeRides.get(i).getRideInstance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeTom2s.size != 0) {
            int activeTom2Length = activeTom2s.size;
            for (int i = activeTom2Length; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeTom2s.get(i).getTom2Instance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeCrashs.size != 0) {
            int activeCrashLength = activeCrashs.size;
            for (int i = activeCrashLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeCrashs.get(i).getCrashInstance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeTom3s.size != 0) {
            int activeTom3Length = activeTom3s.size;
            for (int i = activeTom3Length; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeTom3s.get(i).getTom3Instance(), environment);
            }
        }
        if (activeBasses.size != 0) {
            int activeBassLength = activeBasses.size;
            for (int i = activeBassLength; --i >= 0;) {
                modelBatch.render(activeBasses.get(i).getBassInstance(), environment);
            }
        }
        modelBatch.end();
    }
```

Comment: Provided your method, I can't find the exact reason for FPS drop. In order to diagnose your problem, you'll have to do some GL profiling and look at the values it gives you. Read this in order to do this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Profiling#OpenGL
You're welcome to share the values you get with using the method vs without the method and it'll more help to analyze the problem

Comment: I got these values:

Comment: drawCalls: 55
    shaderSwitches: 14
    Listener: com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.profiling.GLErrorListener$1@2ef2bb8b
    textureBindings: 1
    vertexCount: 55

Comment: Ok I'd say shader switches is a bit high although I don't believe it is the reason for the FPS drop. Try that: comment out every render inside that method. Now uncomment the first one and check if it causes a major drop. If not, try the second one, and the third and so on...
However these values aren't considered high, so there are chances the problem is not with the rendering

Comment: when I uncomment just "modelBatch.render(highwayLines, environment);", I'm getting 54-57fps, and if I uncomment "modelBatch.render(buttons, environment);" I'm getting 30-32fps and so on.. The more render methods I uncomment, the lower fps I get

Comment: Alright. What device are you testing it on? What are the spec? Which Android version? Have you tried it on another mobile device?

Comment: lenovo vibe p1m

Comment: I didn't tried it on another device

Comment: but I think that it should run normal on most devices